# Scanner in a flowchart | Java

Tags: java, flowchart

I don't know how to convert this into a flowchart because of the Scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Voter {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
        int age = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        if (age >= 18) {
            System.out.print("You are eligible to vote");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Nah, you're not allowed to vote");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create a flowchart of the flow through your code? or convert something programatically? please be specific.

Comment: Input is represented by a parallellogram.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use manual input component of flow chart.

Here is the diagram for your code.

[image]